# Error in remote streaming pdf files to Solr

Tags: apache, solr, streaming

I am trying to stream remote files to Solr for indexing using the stream.url parameter as

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv?stream.url=http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/SatoNT.pdf&stream.contentType=application/pdf;charset=utf-8'
```

following the solution here [Remote streaming with Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16858578/1809377). However, the Solr server throws an error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">400</int>
<int name="QTime">518</int>
</lst>       
<lst name="error">
<str name="msg">Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id</str><int name="code">400</int>
</lst>
</response>
```

I tried looking in the Solr documentation and wiki pages but couldn't find a single example. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Here is my schema.xml file - http://pastebin.com/akmruD9N

The problem is there is only one field, i.e., `id` with `required="true" multiValued="false"` properties and that is being used as `uniqueKey` as

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

and there must be a field set as `uniqueKey` else Solr remote streaming doesn't work. Which field should I use instead of `id` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to send PDF file to a legacy CSV import endpoint. So, it does strange things and complains.

You want to use [Extract handler](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler). It covers a lot of information, including giving an example with a PDF file and setting the id explicitly:

> curl "http://example.com:8983/solr/update/extract?stream.file=/path/to/file/StatesLeftToVisit.doc&stream.contentType=application/msword&literal.id=states.doc"

Comment: I had to change `stream.file` to `stream.url` to remote stream a file from url and it worked. I have Solr server deployed on AWS but I am not able to run `curl` command from my local machine. Is it possible to configure Solr to achieve this? Thanks :)

Comment: Might be a different question. And you need to be more precise on *why* you are not able to run curl. Hard to guess.

Comment: The connection to the Solr server times out. Will ask it as a separate question then.